# How does the array SPLIT function sort?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I set up a VBA routine in Word 2013 to create/display a calendar.
An array was set up for the weekdays, here's some of it:

```vb
Public arrDays As Variant 
arrDays = Split("Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun", ",")

    With .Rows(2)
         .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter
         .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
         .Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
         .Range.Font.Italic = True
         .Range.Font.Size = 28
         .Height = 24
         For J = 1 To 7
            .Cells(J).Range.Text = arrDays(J + lngFirstDay - 2)
         Next J
    End With
```

When I place the .Cells(J).Range.Text in the specified cell number it starts with "Sun";
The watch window shows:
arrDays(0) "Sun"; arrDays(1) "Mon"; arrDays(2) "Tue";....

Mo matter how I arrange the weekdays in the split, it is the same.

The calendar routine does work, it's just this Split thing

Info that should have been in the original post:

Start of Calendar selection
[image]

Watch list of arrDays
[image]

First day of workweek - Sunday
[image]

Second day of workweek
[image]

Complete Calendar
[image]

Comment: What value has `lngFirstDay`?

Comment: lngFirstDay value is from the selection box to choose the start of the week, either Sunday or Monday, it'll be set to 1 or 2

Comment: `.Cells(J).Range.Text`? Are you sure the code is working? Because `.Text` is a readonly property. `.Cells(j, 1).Value = "SomeThing"` is the way to do it

Comment: Er, do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  Yes, I do have  "On Error..." as the last item prior to "End Sub".

Comment: @Siddharth Rout the code does work.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed.

I moved `Public arrDays As Variant` from `CallCalForm` to `Declarations` and moved

```vb
arrDays = Split("Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun", ",")
```

from beginning of `CallCalForm` to top `Sub CommandButton1_Click()`.

I'm not sure if moving around made a difference, maybe I had a typo somewhere. If I change the order of arrDays the outcome corresponds to the change.